# Javascript name field masking (Using regular expression)

Tags: javascript, list, masking

i need to mask a name and i want it in Script. 
i have a list format data.
Following is my jsp which put data in a variable.

```
<c:forEach value="${test}" var="v"/>
<c:set var = "nametest" value="${v.name}"
```

i only need names to be shown on the screen. so i made a variable only contains names. The problem is my script function doesn't look like
contain my data correctly. 
Following is my script.

```
function maskingName(nametest){
  var a = "${nametest}"
  if (a === undefined || a ===''){
  return '';
}
var pattern = /.$/;

return a.replace(pattern,"*");
}
```

after running it, i only get the last name (there are 10 names and it shows the only the last one)without masking.

My question is
1. how can i use List format in my script function?
2. why does the regular expression not working?

Thank you!

Comment: java is not javascript and vice versa

Comment: The pattern you have is used to identify a single character for a line(which only have one character and then end of line). Try /.*$/

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small java code that might help you understand better

```
static String maskingName(String nametest) {

    if (nametest == null || nametest == "") {
        return "";
    }
    String pStr = ".$"  // ".*$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pStr);
    return pattern.matcher(nametest).replaceAll("***");
}
```

For input '12345' or '345345', the output will be '1234***' or '34534***'

Replacing `pStr=".*$"` will give output `******`

Comment: Thank you for your help. but either /.$/ or /.*$/ is not working..Think i need to find more...